# Iterating over a bindinglist to find a property

Tags: c#, user-interface, devexpress

I have a BindingList called bList that is getting utilized in a GUI.

```
public BindingList<SomeList> bList = new BindingList<SomeList>();
```

What I'm trying to do is change the RowStyle with an event by checking a property in bList. Let's say in bList I have 6 objects which have multiple properties. One of the properties in bList I have is called `isValid`, which is a `bool`, if that's set to false I turn that row red, else the row just stays the default color.

I was able to get all rows turning red if they are `>= 0`. How can I iterate over `bList` to find the property `isValid` for each object in `blist`?

```
private void gridView_RowStyle(object sender, RowStyleIEventArgs e)
{
    bool isValid = class.bList[0].isValid;

    if (e.RowHandle >= 0)
    {
        if (isValid == false)
        {
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *properties* are going to be members of the objects which the list *contains* not the list itself.  If you want the control to be made aware of changes to the list *items* the class will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to iterate over a BindingList since I can't utilize a `foreach` on the whole list.

Comment: Is the control a DGV and is it using the BindingList as the DataSource?

Comment: I'm bypassing the control which is a DGV from DevExpress DataSource right now and accessing the BindigList directly, each object in the BindingList has 6 properties, one of which is `isValid` which is a `bool`. I'm having a hard time thinking about how I would iterate over the binding  list.

Comment: why use a BindingList if you dont bind it?  thats the point of using it.  *Why* cant you do a `foreach`?  Are you trying to figure out which one changed?

Comment: I haven't tried accessing the DataSource that much, when I did my first tests to handle the event, it seemed like I wouldn't be able to do as much. I'll take a stab at it along with the other examples tomorrow. The issue I have, once I do a `ForEach` of bList, is I don't understand what method to use to store the iterator. I'm not too familiar with a `BindingList`. Checked the docs on MSDN, and it seems its a List<> of some kind. I'm a bit new to C# and I haven't used it in awhile. The `BindingList` in this case hasn't changed, I'm trying to display that the data is not Valid.

Comment: I can't talk in chat yet, I do not have enough reputation, but I figured out the `ForEach` issue I was having. I couldn't figure out the type for the iterator so in `foreach (someType item in bList)`, I couldn't figure out `someType`. Now that I'm able to get the bool`isValid` from each object, I'm still modifying all the rows to turn red.

Answer (score 1):

You should use reflection to get the property value of your object. Here is a sample function that will work for a generic BindingList.

Use:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        object val = null;
        TryGetPropertyValue<SomeType>(myList, i, "isValid", out val);
        bool isValid = Convert.ToBoolean(val);
        // Process logic for isValid value
    }
```

Method:

```
static private bool TryGetPropertyValue<T>(BindingList<T> bindingList, int classIndex, string propertyName, out object val)
    where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

            val = propertyInfo.GetValue(bindingList[classIndex], null);

            return val != null; // return true if val is not null and false if it is
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            val = null;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the color of a row based on a property value, you should add that property as a hidden column and then use that cell's value to set the style.

See the following:
[How to change a row style based on a column value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A264)

For your problem:

```
private void gridView_RowCellStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
   string valid = gridView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "isValid").ToString().ToLower();
   if(valid == "true") 
      e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

To add a hidden column:
[Hide Column in GridView but still grab the values](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q361040)

Answer (score 0):

I'm now able to iterate over the `BindingList` bList because I had some other issues with inheritance trying to figure out what type for the iterator.

```
foreach (SomeType item in bList)
{
     if (e.RowHandle >= 0)
     {
          if (instance.isValid == false)
          {
              e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
          }
          else
          {
              e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White;
          }
     }
}
```

How come all the rows are still turning red even though I'm finding which object with the property `isValid` is returning `false`.